# Is it better to start a sentence with “If ” or “Where”?

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following sentences is better to use?

> 1. Where it is concluded that the report is incorrect it will be returned.
> 2. If the report is incorrect then it will be returned.

Or do they mean the same thing?

These sentences will be used for a description of activities.

Comment: Just keep it simple: “incorrect reports will be returned”.

Comment: I would encourage you to reserve 'where' for cases *where* there may be multiple instances and a return for each. However, it doesn't look like your example merits this. So, I would prefer 'if'. 'Wherein', 'insofar as', or 'inasmuch as' would be clearer than 'where', but 'if' is shorter, perhaps clearer, and more common. JanusBahsJacquet is right, though, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your examples, the sentence starting with *if* is easier to understand. But it always depends on the context of what's being written as well as target audience. I find *where* is used more often in formal writings, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

**If**.

If you use *where*, the sentence is harder to parse. You run the risk of confusing your audience, who might think that you're talking about a location.

Answer (score 0):

"Where" is making a more general statement. In particular the statement with "if" would be appropriate whether we were talking about a particular report right now, or about any report which might happen to be produced; "where" would be appropriate only in the latter case. 
Apart from that, I agree with vehomzzz and joshdick